# Add/Hide a div after click again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add/hide a dive after a click. For now, I'm able to add a div when I click on a button. Then, I can remove the div if I click on Close. The problem is that I can't readd the div if I click again on a button without reloading the page. It's like that if my dive is remove, it can't reappear.

Here is my code :

```js
$('.close-div').on('click', function(){
$(this).closest("#closeme").remove();
});
```

```html
<ul class="" role="tablist">
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsports" href="#vtab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Sports</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsante" href="#vtab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Santé</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublisharts" href="#vtab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Arts</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsci" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Sciences et technologies</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishgastro" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Gastronomie</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsocial" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Social</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Autres</a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="closeme">
         <div class="alert tab-pane fade" id="vtab1">
         <div class="close-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="close-div">Close</a>
    </div>
          <h3 class="title">Sports</h3>
          <p>Trouvez des sportifs dans l'âme sur Benevolo pour vous aider dans vos tournois, compétitions.</p>
         </div>
```

Does anyone know how to readd a div after you removed it ? I don't know how to be more clear/precise ? Thanks (I have did some research, but I don't really code in js so I can't really deal with lot of codes...) !

Comment: _"able to add a div when I click on a button. "_ Can include portion of `js` where `div` is added to `document` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your logic! **The "close" button is inside of the div that goes hidden onclick event. So, if you click it, you just can't click it again (because it will be hidden)** and the event will not be fired to show it again!

So, a solution is to show the div when the other buttons are clicked.

[Your code working](https://jsfiddle.net/FacuCode/L90t5mdL/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('.btn').on('click',function () {
    debugger;
    var div = $("#closeme");
    div.css('display', 'block'); // it shows
});

$('.close-div').on('click', function () {
    var div = $("#closeme");
    div.css('display', 'none'); // it hides
});
```

Or you could just use **hide** and **show** functions as **"HC_"** user said:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function () {
    debugger;
    var div = $("#closeme");
    div.show();
});

$('.close-div').on('click', function () {
    var div = $("#closeme");
    div.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem. I mixed your answer with "HC_" one ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.remove();`

Use `.hide();` and `.show();`

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

You may also enjoy experimenting with `.slideToggle();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.toggle()` command on the click.  That is jQuery and I believe it could solve your problem well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      </head>
      <body>
      <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#close').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#closeme').toggle('hide');
          });
     });
   </script>



       <div class="tab-content" id="closeme" name="closeme" >
       <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish   btnpublishsports" href="#vtab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Sports</a></li>
        <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsante" href="#vtab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Santé</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublisharts" href="#vtab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Arts</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsci" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Sciences et technologies</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishgastro" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Gastronomie</a></li>
         <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish btnpublishsocial" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Social</a></li>
        <li class="listlayer6publish"><a class="btn btn-dark btnpublish" href="#vtab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Autres</a></li>
      </div>
        <div class="alert tab-pane fade" id="vtab1">
        <div class="close-wrapper">

      </div>
        <input type='button' id="close" name="close" value='hide/show'>
        <h3 class="title">Sports</h3>
        <p>Trouvez des sportifs dans l'âme sur Benevolo pour vous aider dans vos tournois, compétitions.</p>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: try this its working fine and tell me if there is any problem

Comment: You should hide it but not remove the div